# Split a paragraph into 100 characters arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to split my paragraph into 100 characters arrays. But my algorithm doesn't work...

In my output the first one I get 100 characters. But second one I get 200, Next one I get 300 I think...

```
    $desc = $this->getDescription();

    $desc = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/', ' ', strip_tags(html_entity_decode($desc)));
    $desc = preg_replace('/(\s\s+|\t|\n)/', ' ', $desc);

    $count = strlen($desc);
    $time = ($count/100);

    $x = 0;
    $y = 100;


    for($i = 0; $i<ceil($time);$i++){
        $array[$i] = substr($desc,$x,$y);
        $array[$i] = str_replace(" ", "+", $array[$i]);
        $link[$i] = 'http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=' . $array[$i];
        $x+= 100;
        $y+= 100;
    }
```

Does anybody know the problem?

The output I get:

Where I tried to debug it...

```
Characters: 100 |  x: 0 | y: 100 |
|Characters: 200 |  x: 100 | y: 200 |
|Characters: 300 |  x: 200 | y: 300 |
|Characters: 400 |  x: 300 | y: 400 |
|Characters: 422 |  x: 400 | y: 500 |
|Characters: 322 |  x: 500 | y: 600 |
|Characters: 222 |  x: 600 | y: 700 |
|Characters: 122 |  x: 700 | y: 800 |
|Characters: 22 |  x: 800 | y: 900
```

Comment: You can use wordwrap also. And you need to get 0 - 99, 100 - 199, etc..

Answer (score 1):

$y is the length, and you are increasing it by 100 on every step of the loop.

I recommend to comment or delete the line :

```
$y+= 100;
```

Comment: or, `substr($desc,$x,100);`

Comment: Thanks that was the issue. I didn't know it was working that way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$str= "If the optional split_length parameter is specified, the returned array will be broken down into chunks with each being split_length in length, otherwise each chunk will be one character in length. If the optional split_length parameter is specified, the returned array will be broken down into chunks with each being split_length in length, otherwise each chunk will be one character in length. If the optional split_length parameter is specified, the returned array will be broken down into chunks with each being split_length in length, otherwise each chunk will be one character in length. If the optional split_length parameter is specified, the returned array will be broken down into chunks with each being split_length in length, otherwise each chunk will be one character in length. If the optional split_length parameter is specified, the returned array will be broken down into chunks with each being split_length in length, otherwise each chunk will be one character in length. If the optional split_length parameter is specified, the returned array will be broken down into chunks with each being split_length in length, otherwise each chunk will be one character in length. If the optional split_length parameter is specified, the returned array will be broken down into chunks with each being split_length in length, otherwise each chunk will be one character in length. If the optional split_length parameter is specified, the returned array will be broken down into chunks with each being split_length in length, otherwise each chunk will be one character in length.";

$arr = str_split($str, 100);
print"<pre>";
print_r($arr);
```